# PyTorch - custom loss function - calculations outside graph

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, data-modeling

I'm kinda new to pytorch and trying to wrap my head around it.
I've read about custom loss functions and as far as I've seen, they cannot be decoupled from internal computational graph. This means loss function consumes tensors, does operations on them, which are implemented in pytorch, and outputs tensor. Is there any way to have decoupled loss calculation and plug it back somehow?

**Use case**

I'm trying to train an encoder, where latent space will be optimized to some statistical quality. This means I don't train in batches and I calculate single loss value for whole epoch and whole data set. Is it even possible to teach net that way?

```py
class Encoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, genome_size: int):
        super(Encoder, self).__init__()

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(genome_size, genome_size)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(genome_size, genome_size)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(genome_size, genome_size)

        self.genome_size = genome_size

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        x = self.fc3(x)

        return x
```

```py
def train_encoder(
    net: nn.Module,
    optimizer: Optimizer,
    epochs: int,
    population: Tensor,
    fitness: Tensor,
):
    running_loss = 0.0

    for epoch in range(epochs):

        optimizer.zero_grad()
        outputs = net(population)

        # encoder_loss is computationally heavy and cannot be done only on tensors
        # I need to unwrap those tensors to numpy arrays and use them as an input to another model
        loss = encoder_loss(outputs, fitness)
        running_loss += loss

        running_loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        print('Encoder loss:', loss)
```

I've seen some examples with accumulated `running_loss`, but my encoder is unable to learn anything. Convergence plot just jumps all over the place.

Thanks for your time <3

Comment: Also, not sure a single step per epoch (aka batched gradient descent) will work well, in many real world cases it doesn't.

Comment: @jodag I'm aware of that. It's just purely theoretical work.

Comment: > You would want to optimizer.zero_grad() once at the beginning of the epoch

It seems I'm zeroing at the beginning. Should I move it outside?

Comment: Ah I missread some of your code, sorry about that. basically the only thing that seems wrong to me is the running loss part. you should only .backward on the loss term for that epoch, not the running loss.

Comment: Right now `loss` is decoupled. How the gradient update works then?

Comment: So each time you call backward on the loss it accumulats gradients to the weights. If you want to perform backpropagation using the gradients from all previous epochs then all you would need to do is not zero the gradients between epochs. I'm not sure if this is your goal or if I'm still misunderstanding. But accumulating gradients for multiple loss functions is mathematically equivalent to computing the gradients for the sum of those loss functions by linearity of differentiation.

Comment: @jodag Please repost your comment as a post. I'll mark it as answered.

Comment: Note that if `encoder_loss` copies the tensors to numpy arrays and does operations there, autograd cannot tell the gradient of your loss function wrt the parameters. You would need to write your own gradient function for the loss in this case